# Problem with legs and meshes in vrm model (bones)

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

my problem has to do with a vrm model that i imported into Blender.
I attached the mesh of the boot to the amature with automatic weights.
For some reason if i test it, when i move one leg the mesh of the other one comes with it.
[image]

Comment: please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that the meshes may possibly be linked to each other, so when you move/alter the mesh of one, the mesh of the other is moved an altered as well. You can try separating the meshes/objects.

1. Select the boot
2. Go to Object-->relations-->make single user-->Object & data

The other issue is that you may have somehow linked both boots to the same bone/armature.. You may have to unattach them and reattach them separately after making sure that only the materials/texture is linked, and not the meshes.

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour @Hukinator